# Resize images for table cells in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css, image, web, resize

I have a code like this:

HTML:

```
<nav>
    <table id="menuBar">
        <tr>
            <td> <img src="data/Sources/menu.png"> </td>
            <td> <img src="data/Sources/home.png"> </td>
            <td> Files </td>
            <td> Comments </td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
    background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#menuBar{
    padding: 5%;
}

#menuBar img{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    display: block;
}
```

And I want to fit the pictures into the cells.

But the pictures are bigger than the cells, and they are resizing the table instead of resizing the images themselves. Can't figure it out. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Have you looked into background-size: cover?

Comment: try the `overflow: hidden` or other suitable property values of overflow. Add this part to the table cells <td>s

Comment: if i add   `#menuBar td{
    background-size: cover;
    overflow: scroll;
}` still doesnt work

Comment: I am not sure if I am following the question the best, but would giving the image max-width and max-height in pixels (like 100px) would do what you need it to do?

Comment: Yeah, that works, but I want the page to be responsive. If i do it like this the images are always 100px high and 100px wide. I want them to resize with the page. Also this wouldnt work if I had rectangle shaped image. But still thank you for your advice :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `max-width: 100%;` in place of width.

Further add `max-height: 100%;` to prevent the mage from changing the aspect ration of the image(for exact image viewing experience)

and also add full width to the table

```
#menuBar{
    padding: 5%;
  height:90%;
  width:90%;
}
```

```css
nav {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
    background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#menuBar{
    padding: 5%;
  height:90%;
  width:90%;
}

#menuBar img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <table id="menuBar">
            <tr>
                <td> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgm7x.jpg?s=328&g=1"> </td>
                <td> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgm7x.jpg?s=328&g=1"> </td>
                <td> Files </td>
                <td> Comments </td>
            </tr>
        </table>  
</nav>
```

but  would recommend to use div in these situations which works best for responsive designs

```css
nav {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 25%;
    padding-right: 25%;
    background-color: #7F7F7F;
}

#menuBar{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}

#menuBar div{
  float:left;
    height: 100%;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#menuBar img{
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div id="menuBar">
            <div> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgm7x.jpg?s=328&g=1"> </div>
                <div> <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cgm7x.jpg?s=328&g=1"> </div>
                <div> Files </div>
                <div> Comments </div>
        </div>  
</nav>
```

Comment: The image still makes the table bigger than the nav.  Size of the image is 512x512.

Comment: I am not sure if I am following the question the best, but would giving the image max-width and max-height in pixels (like 100px) would do what you need it to do?

Comment: This was the ticket for me.  I was able to use both `max-width:2.5cm` and `max-height:2.5cm`for my print format HTML, within a `<td>` element with much success.